# Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) - Push Notification (Java)

Tags: java, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

Estou trabalhando em um backend que gostaria de usar para enviar / Push notificações para app android utilizando o **Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)**.

Já li algumas vezes a documentação ([FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)) mas continuo com muitas dúvidas.

Sei que é possível utilizar o SDK Admin ou algum outro protocolo do servidor, mas o que decidi foi usar o SDK Admin.

Já Fiz o cadastro no Console do Firebase, gerei a chave do servidor e também outras chaves necessárias.

**Segue a baixo o exemplo de uma mensagem:**

```
POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/nome_projeto/messages:send HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer ya29.ElqKBGN2Ri_Uz...HnS_uNreA

{
 "message":{
   "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
   "notification":{
     "body" : "Primeira Mensagem FCM!",
     "title" : "Mensagem FCM"
  }
}
```

**Segue parte do meu fonte:**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
  <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
  <version>5.8.0</version>
</dependency>


private Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("./service-account.json");
private InputStream resourceInputStream;

public String obterAccessToken() throws IOException {
    resourceInputStream = resource.getInputStream();
    GoogleCredential googleCredential = GoogleCredential
        .fromStream(resourceInputStream)
        .createScoped(Collections.singletonList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging"));
    googleCredential.refreshToken();
    return googleCredential.getAccessToken();
}


public void iniciarFirebase() throws IOException {
    resourceInputStream = resource.getInputStream();
    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(resourceInputStream))
        .build();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
}
```

E agora? Como faço para enviar a mensagem para um App?

Preciso gerar um Json com as informações destes dois métodos?

Comment: o AdminSDK do firebase não suporta envio de notificações ainda segundo a documentação: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Comment: è possivel enviar a notificação com uma chamada via HTTP no servidor FCM: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

Comment: Muito útil as duas dicas. Estou tentando também fazer funcionar o exemplo que postou. Nunca usei e estou tentando aprender o Retrofit2 (Call).

Comment: É bem facil, eu fiz em um projeto onde o banckend tinha que notificar os usuarios, e no backend e mais facil ainda usar retrofit, pois não precisa fazer chamada asincrona, vc pode executar a chamada direta que o main thread suporta, caso vc nao queira tratar tudo como Entidade, vc pode usar a lib Okhttp para tratar tudo direto da camada de rede

Comment: No exemplo, o sendPush(Map<String, Object> param) não está aceitando o retorno do return response.body(). Ainda não entendi o pq...

Comment: Na vdd,a sintax esta incorreta, pois o retorno do metodo é VOID e nao aceita Retorno, pois eu fiz muitos metodos de envio e alguns deles eu fiz execução assincrona, pois nao precisava saber o resultado

Comment: Editei e alterei para a sintax correta

Comment: Se eu usar da forma como está agora (public FirebasePushResponse sendPush(Map<String, Object> param) ) ainda continua com o seguinte erro : The return type is incompatible with 
  FirebaseCall.sendPush(Map<String,Object>). Estou tentando fazer um exemplo mais simples aqui para tentar entender.

Comment: Eu omiti o conversor, porque vc pode escolher o a lib de sua preferencia, aqui nesse exemplo ele mostra como adicionar um conversor 
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-adding-customizing-the-gson-converter

Comment: O Conversor serve para vc tratar as respostas, como um framework REST vc trata as respostas diretamente como entidade e não como Json, mas para isso vc precisa mapear as respostas com uma biblioteca JSON, no caso do exemplo vc usa a Gson (biblioteca do google)

Comment: Está quase... Agora acontece o seguinte erro: Exception in thread com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `br.com.teste.FirebasePushResponse` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (okhttp3.ResponseBody$BomAwareReader); line: 1, column: 2]...     Obrigadooooo

Comment: è por isso que gosto de usar GSON, ela não precisa de muitos tratamentos, mas tbm é limitado a forma de mapear, mas vc pode tentar essa solução para seu erro com jackson: http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-exception

Comment: Mudei para GSON amigo... Foi sem erro algum. 
FirebasePush: sucess.  Ufaaaaaaa.
Agora para testar se está enviando corretamente o push preciso instalar um app em um celular? Consegue algum que posso testar? Ou preciso "fazer" um?
Muito obrigadooooooooo mais uma vez

Comment: Rlx, alguns topicos podem demorar até dias para serem sincronizados  Android/IOS, mas se vc mandar a chamada para o topic default, vai funcionar de certeza, mas é bem facil fazer o push notification no android, ja tem uns modelos prontos no proprio android studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizando a biblioteca [Retrofit2](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) para enviar Requisição no java, eu implementei as seguintes classes e metodos

```
class NotificationService {

    private FirebaseCall firebaseCall;

    public NotificationService() {

        Retrofit r = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://fcm.googleapis.com/").build();

        firebaseCall = r.create(FirebaseCall.class);

    }

    /**
     * Envia notificação para um dispositivo unico
     * 
     * @param mensagem
     * @param action
     * @param device
     */
    public void sendNotificationDevice(String mensagem, String action, String device) {

        Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("message", mensagem);
        data.put("action", action);
        sendPush(getDataDevice(device, data), this);

    }

    /**
     * Envia notificação para um canal
     * 
     * @param channel
     * @param mensagem
     * @param title
     * @param action
     */
    public void sendNotification(String channel, String mensagem, String title, String action) {

        Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("message", mensagem);
        data.put("title", title);
        data.put("action", action);
        sendPush(getDataTopic(channel, data), this);
    }

    /**
     * Aqui é feita a chamada da requisição
     */
    public FirebasePushResponse sendPush(Map<String, ?> param, Callback<FirebasePushResponse> callback) {
        Response<FirebasePushResponse> response = null;
        try {
            response = firebaseCall.sendPush(param).execute();
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                logger.info("FirebasePush: sucess");
            } else {
                logger.error("FirebasePush: erro");
                logger.error("Code: " + response.code() + "\n\rmessege: " + response.message());
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            showErro(e);
        }

        return response.body();

    }



    /**
     * Map para notificar um dispositivo unico
     * 
     * @param to
     *            codigo do FirebaseInstanceId do dispositivo data channel
     * @param data
     * @return map
     */
    public Map<String, ?> getDataDevice(String to, Map<String, String> data) {

        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        String toRaw = to;
        map.put("to", toRaw);
        map.put("data", data);

        return map;
    }

    /**
     * envia notificação para um TOPIC
     * 
     * @param to
     *            data channel
     * @param data
     * @return map
     */
    public Map<String, ?> getDataTopic(String to, Map<String, ? extends Object> data) {

        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        String toRaw = "/topics/" + to;
        map.put("to", toRaw);
        map.put("data", data);

        return map;
    }



    public FirebasePushResponse sendPush(Map<String, Object> param) {
        Response<FirebasePushResponse> response = null;
        try {
            response = firebaseCall.sendPush(param).execute();
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                logger.info("FirebasePush: sucess");
            } else {
                logger.error("FirebasePush: erro");
                logger.error("Code: " + response.code() + "\n\rmessege: " + response.message());
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            showErro(e);
        }

        return response.body();
    }
}

interface FirebaseCall {
    static final String PATH = "fcm/send";

    @POST(PATH)
    @Headers({ "Authorization:key=" + INSIRA_SUA_CHAVE_DO_FIREBASE_AQUI, "Content-Type:application/json" })
    public Call<FirebasePushResponse> sendPush(@Body Object object);

    @POST(PATH)
    @Headers({ "Authorization:key=" + INSIRA_SUA_CHAVE_DO_FIREBASE_AQUI, "Content-Type:application/json" })
    public Call<FirebasePushResponse> sendPush(@Body Map<String, Object> object);
}

class FirebasePushResponse {

    private String messageId, error;

}
```

E para utilizar basta chamar a classe

```
NotificationService notification = new NotificationService();
FirebasePushResponse resposta = notification.sendNotification("default","Hello World","Hellow Title","br.com.action.sync");
```

Para receber notificação por um topico vc deve estar com os dispositivos sincronizados no topico

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("default");
```

Answer (score 2):

Olá,

É uma pena que este post esteja em português porque a documentação sobre o FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) está completamente escassa em todo o Mundo e em inglês poderia ajudar mais pessoas, mas vamos as respostas.

O exemplo abaixo é completamente didático e deve ser adequado a um ambiente de produção.

1 - Você deve acessar o Firebase e chegar até o "SDK Admin do Firebase", lá você deve clicar em "Gerar nova chave privada" (caso ainda não tenha gerado uma).

2 - Essa chave é um json com a estrutura abaixo e deve ser salva em um arquivo:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "xxxxxxx",
  "private_key_id": "xxxxxxx",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----xxxxxxx -----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "xxxxxxx",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/xxxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

3 - Você deve importar o pacote abaixo em seu projeto.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
        <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
        <version>6.3.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

4 - Segue abaixo o código-fonte de exemplo

```
public class FCMService  {

    public void send(String idPush, String msg)  {

        try {

            GoogleCredentials fromStream = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(new File("/path para o json gerado no passo 2")));

            FirebaseOptions firebaseOptions = new FirebaseOptions.Builder().setConnectTimeout(10000).setCredentials(fromStream).build();

            FirebaseApp firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(firebaseOptions);

            FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance(firebaseApp);

            Message message = Message.builder().putData("msg", msg).setToken(idPush).build();

            String response = firebaseMessaging.send(message);

            System.out.println(response);

        } catch (FirebaseMessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

PS: Vale lembrar que a Google está constantemente mudando o FCM o que tem deixado todo mundo perdido. A solução acima já utiliza o novo endpoint do FCM (https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/{parent=projects/*}/messages:send) e não mais o endpoint legado que muitas bibliotecas ainda estão apontando (https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send).